# Converting an XNA game from WINDOWS to XBOX

Tags: xna, windows, xbox

I have an XNA game for WINDOWS which I want to work on XBOX also.

I've designed the game so that when I want to connect it to an XBOX, all I have to do is supply a different input class,

And I would do that by checking with the preprocessor macros and checking if it's windows or xbox.

But then, when I tried to do `Create a copy of this project for XBOX` in VisualStudio, it created several new projects (the real XNA project and some of it's dependencies), and it complained about things not working for `C# 3.0` and that I should use `C# 4.0` instead, which I didn't find out how to do either.

What's the correct way to make both WINDOWS and XBOX versions of an XNA game?

And also, how do I really run the game on XBOX? I haven't found a good tutorial on how I do that... also I don't have an XboxLive membership so if there's a hacky way to do that, it's better

Comment: What version XNA and what version of the dotNet are you using in the original project?

Comment: Xna 4, dotnet 4

Answer (score -1):

If you've already supplied the input methods, then this code should work (change in Program.cs)

```
#if XBOX
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    using (Game1 game = new Game1())
    {
        game.Run();
    }
}
#endif
```

When you open a new project, the #if says WINDOWS || XBOX, but, if you just want an Xbox game, then change it to Xbox only.

Comment: I've left the project already, but for the sake of the answer, the problem is not about allowing only XBOX. It's about how to check the game in XBOX when I don't have xbox GOLD, and also compiling the game correctly for XBOX.